# Django IntegrityError with get_or_create

Tags: python, mysql, django

Im having an issue with Django's get_or_create, i have seen this issue in a few posts already explaning that its a MySQL issue, so i followed this post
http://www.no-ack.org/2010/07/mysql-transactions-and-django.html

Which basically says that `get_or_create` will return an `IntegrityError` when creating objects concurrently because of MySQL's default transaction-isolation of `REPEATABLE READ`.

I did as the post suggested which was to add `transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED` to my 
`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, but got the same error. So im wondering if there's any other solution.

Here's a sample model to replicate the issue

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeingKey(Author)
```

If i have a long list of authors and books, some repeated. And i run a forloop to iterate through each author/book using get_or_create to create or get the respective object, it will throw an IntegrityError.

The loop is something similar to..

```
authors = ['Author1', 'Author2', 'Author3', 'Author4', 'Author5']
books = ['book1', 'book2', 'book3', 'book4', 'book5']

for author, book in zip(authors, books):
    author = Author.objects.get_or_create(name=author)[0]
    author.book_set.get_or_create(name=book) # Error happens here
```

Comment: can you show the code that you are using in the loop as well?

Comment: I'm not really sure what happens when you do `author.book_set.get_or_create(name=book)`. I would personally do it more explicitly: `Book.objects.get_or_create(name=book, defaults={'author':author})` or something like that. Could you post your exact error? might help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your shouldn't use `get_or_create` with fields that are not unique in the database. One way to avoid this issue would be to enforce uniqueness of the name field:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the unique parameter, in my actual code i do have it, that was just a sample